# Samba: Windows' user missing home directory

Tags: windows-7, samba

I'm having issues with the home directory not showing up after logging in. I can add the home directory manually.

The letter H: is missing when I try to map it manually though. It seems it's already assigned the letter but nothing is showing up.

Here's a sample of the samba configuration.

```
[global]
workgroup = EBT
netbios name = filestore
passdb backend = tdbsam
add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd -m %u
delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel -r %u
add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd %g
delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel %g
add user to group script = /usr/sbin/groupmod -A %u %g
delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/groupmod -R %u %g
add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -s /bin/false -d /var/lib/nobody %u
# Note: The following specifies the default logon script.
# Per user logon scripts can be specified in the user account using pdbedit
logon script = scripts\%U.bat
# This sets the default profile path. Set per user paths with pdbedit
logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%U
logon drive = H:
logon home = \\%L\%U
domain logons = Yes
os level = 35
preferred master = Yes
domain master = Yes
idmap uid = 15000-20000
idmap gid = 15000-20000
ldap ssl = No
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
log level = 3

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
valid users = %S
read only = No
browseable = No
hide files = /desktop.ini/ntuser.ini/NTUSER.*/
```

Comment: It turns out to be simply the H: drive being allocated to the card reader.